# Why are certain games only available on iPad?

Tags: applications, ipod-touch, ios-appstore

I recently bought a 5th generation iPod touch. I searched for "Magic 2014" but was greeted with the message:

"Magic 2014 is only available on Apple iPad".

Why are certain games iPad only?

Answer (score 7):

The most simple answer probably is *because the developer decided accordingly*. There might be several more specific reasons, the most relevant is probably that some games just need a bigger screen and/or it's too cumbersome to maintain two GUI versions in parallel.